# At / on the right setting

Tags: prepositions

In the sentence:

> The camera is **at / on** the right settings.

Being a learner I suppose it should be **at** since we use **at** to refer to specific points on a scale.

But I heard someone using **on** in this context.

What is the opinion of a native speaker?

Answer (score 1):

"On the right setting" and "at the right setting" are interchangeable.

However, I think that a native English speaker would say, "The camera has the right settings" or "The settings on the camera are right" or "The camera's settings are right."

"The camera is on/at the right settings" sounds unnatural to me. "The dials are on/at the right settings" would be correct.